# How can I use programmatically read properties from a .msi file?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, apache-poi, windows-installer

I have a Spring Boot application where the client can upload .msi files. When the client does so, I need to access some information that the .msi file holds. For example the icon, application name, language, bitness (32-bit og 64-bit), etc.

I've tried to use the Apache POI library to accomplish that.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
    <version>2.11.0</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
    <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
    <version>5.2.5</version>
</dependency>
```

This is my attempt:

```
@PostMapping(value = "file/upload", consumes = "application/octet-stream")
@Operation(summary = "upload file")
public ResponseEntity<?> uploadFile() {
    try {
        // Specify the path to the file
        String filePath = "C:\\MyFile.msi";

        // Read the file from the desktop
        POIFSFileSystem poifs = new POIFSFileSystem(new FileInputStream(filePath));
        DirectoryEntry dir = poifs.getRoot();
        DocumentEntry dsiEntry = (DocumentEntry) dir.getEntry(DocumentSummaryInformation.DEFAULT_STREAM_NAME);

        DocumentInputStream dis = new DocumentInputStream(dsiEntry);
        PropertySet ps = new PropertySet(dis);
        DocumentSummaryInformation dsi = new DocumentSummaryInformation(ps);
        SummaryInformation si = new SummaryInformation(ps);

        // Test print property values to console
        System.out.println(si.getAuthor());
        System.out.println(si.getVerison());
        ...
    ...
}
```

As you can see I'm getting a .msi file from my C: disk and to test that it works I'm trying to print some of the properties to the console.

This code throws an error on this line: 
`PropertySet ps = new PropertySet(dis);`

The error is this:

`Handler dispatch failed: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'org.apache.commons.io.output.UnsynchronizedByteArrayOutputStream$Builder org.apache.commons.io.output.UnsynchronizedByteArrayOutputStream.builder()'`

Comment: If you just want the OLE2 properties from POI, safer way is via HPSFPropertiesOnlyDocument rather than trying to initialise the HPFS objects directly, see https://github.com/apache/poi/blob/trunk/poi/src/main/java/org/apache/poi/hpsf/extractor/HPSFPropertiesExtractor.java for it in action

Comment: Is that the correct method to create a PropertySet? Check out the documentation, it looks like PropertySetFactory is what you might need https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/hpsf/PropertySetFactory.html#create-org.apache.poi.poifs.filesystem.DirectoryEntry-java.lang.String-

Comment: @Gagravarr I tried to use HPSFPropertiesOnlyDocument, however I can't access the properties.. It might have something to do with the fact that the file is sent as a HttpServletRequest... Not sure...

Comment: @experimentunit1998X Tried both, they both give the same error.

Comment: Try with a file on disk first?

Comment: @Gagravarr Just tried with file on the disk, it still throws the error:

`Handler dispatch failed: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'org.apache.commons.io.output.UnsynchronizedByteArrayOutputStream$Builder org.apache.commons.io.output.UnsynchronizedByteArrayOutputStream.builder()'`

Comment: You'll need to upgrade your version of Apache Commons IO to the minimum level that Apache POI requires

Comment: @Gagravarr I'm using 2.11.0 which should be compatible. I've even tried the latest, and it doesn't do any difference.

Comment: Make sure you remove any older copies too! The error you have posted suggests you have an old copy on your classpath messing it up

Comment: @Gagravarr Been through all dependencies, and everything should be good.